# How to develop a JS file to be used by web pages (instead of Node.js) with TSC?

Tags: typescript

I'm developing a typescript application, that will of course be compiled into .js files, that will be run on web pages. The required dependencies of the application will be loaded by the web pages with tag `<script>`.

How do I not `import` anything from the dependencies in my .ts files, and can still compile my .ts files with TSC successfully?

If I don't `import` symbols from dependencies, "TS2304: Cannot find name ..." will happen, but it makes no sense to `import` them because I'm not building a Note.js application. The webpage will import them with `<script>`. Any suggestion? Thanks.